# How to show the required message

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I want to show a required message in this small code using the required attribute in input tag

```
<input type="file" id="imgFile" name="imgFile" class="form-control" required />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can leverage **Built-in form validation** which uses HTML5 form validation features. This validation generally doesn't require much JavaScript. Built-in form validation has better performance than JavaScript, but it is not as customizable as JavaScript validation.

Now to leverage the power of built-in form validation, you need to use `form`. Like the example below. Now when you click on `submit` button, validation will automatically fire.

```
<form>
  <input type="file" id="imgFile" name="imgFile" class="form-control" required />
  <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```